# Offline centos install psutil

Tags: python, centos, psutil

I am working on CentOS machine which cannot connect to internet, for some reasons I need to install a python module psutil, so I got psutil-2.1.3 package but not there is no clear instruction how manually one can install it in centOS system

Answer (score 0):

This is usually pretty simple:

1. Got to [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil#downloads)
2. Download the `.whl` file for your Python version and copy it to your server
3. Run `pip install path/to/wheel.whl`, depending on your seetings you might need to install this with sudo or from a virtual environment
4. ???
5. Profit!

Comment: psutil dont have centos binary or wheel (.whl) on pypi.com, it only has source for linux os. for windows it has .whl file.

https://pypi.org/project/psutil/#files